# How does PHP fstat() function work?

Tags: php, performance, filesize, fstat

How does PHP fstat() function work?

Does the function read file size **from disk** on every call?

Or does the function **calculate** the size based on all writing operations performed?

Example:

```
$filename='abc.txt';

$fp=fopen($filename, 'a');

$fstat=fstat($fp);
echo 'Size: '.$fstat['size'].'<br><br>';

echo 'Writing...<br><br>';
fwrite($fp, 'xx');
fwrite($fp, 'yyyy');
// ...
// Some number of fwrite() opertions
// ...
fwrite($fp, 'zzzzzz');

$fstat=fstat($fp);
echo 'Size after writing: '.$fstat['size'].'<br>';
// Does the size is read from disk or is calculated based on earlier writing operations?

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Every `fstat` call it will read from disk.

Comment: Do you think that something is not working as expected? Then you should rephrase your question. Additionally, keep in mind that results might get [cached](http://php.net/clearstatcache)

Comment: [Here is the source code in c](https://github.com/php/php-src) look for `fstat`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are asking because the size is not as you expect. And I suspect it is not as you expect because you read the size **before** closing the file when some writes are still buffered.

Try closing the file **first** and then using `stat()`:

```
$filename='abc.txt';
$fp=fopen($filename, 'a');

$fstat=fstat($fp);
fwrite($fp, 'xx');
fwrite($fp, 'yyyy');
...
...
fclose($fp);


$stat=stat($filename);
echo 'Size after writing: '.$stat['size'].'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tests I think the function fstat() calculates the size because it is much more faster than filesize() with clearstatcache().

The code:

```
for (/*loop for 10 000 files*/) {
    fwrite($fp, '123');
    $fstat=fstat($fp);
    fwrite($fp, '123');
    $fstat=fstat($fp);
    fwrite($fp, '123');
    $fstat=fstat($fp);
}
```

is similar (in preformance) to:

```
// Here filesize() is BUFFERED and gives wrong results
for (/*loop for 10 000 files*/) {
    fwrite($fp, '123');
    $fsize=filesize($filename);

    fwrite($fp, '123');
    $fsize=filesize($filename);

    fwrite($fp, '123');
    $fsize=filesize($filename);
}
```

is faster than:

```
// Here filesize() reads size on every call
for (/*loop for 10 000 files*/) {
    fwrite($fp, '123');
    clearstatcache();
    $fsize=filesize($filename);

    fwrite($fp, '123');
    clearstatcache();
    $fsize=filesize($filename);

    fwrite($fp, '123');
    clearstatcache();
    $fsize=filesize($filename);
}
```

and than:

```
// Here filesize() reads size on every call
for (/*loop for 10 000 files*/) {
    fwrite($fp, '123');
    clearstatcache(true, $filename);
    $fsize=filesize($filename);

    fwrite($fp, '123');
    clearstatcache(true, $filename);
    $fsize=filesize($filename);

    fwrite($fp, '123');
    clearstatcache(true, $filename);
    $fsize=filesize($filename);
}
```

Comment: How did you measure the performance? For such small files, this should be near to impossible

Comment: I have measured it for 10 000 files with different size.